# Exclude a file from find command

Tags: find

How do I exclude the last file from being selected by find command?

```
[root@web1 shantanu]# find /home/wcuser/ -name "catalina.out"
/home/user/services/logs/catalina.out
/home/user/services/logs/catalina.out
/home/user/cash/logs/catalina.out
```

I want to exclude the file "/home/user/cash/logs/catalina.out" from being shown up since it is very old log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by one of the following commands:

```
find /home/wcuser/ \( -name "catalina.out" ! -wholename "/home/user/cash/logs/catalina.out" \)


find /home/wcuser/ \( -name "catalina.out" -and ! -wholename "/home/user/cash/logs/catalina.out" \)
```